# boost::resulf_of or BOOST_TYPEOF in return value type

Tags: c++, boost, typeof

all!
I'm stuck with boost::result_of and BOOST_TYPEOF.
I wanna use them for deducing return value type of method.

How can I implement something like this (this doesn't compile):

```
class A {
  private: 
   int x_; 
  public:
   BOOST_TYPEOF(x_) x() { return x_; }
};
```

Later I'll make macro that creates getters automatically.

Comment: what error does this give? and since this is a rather contrived example, how do you actually intend to use this?

Comment: your example (copied verbatim) compiles correctly under G++  4.6.1

Comment: Do you use --std=c++0x? I compile with VS2010 and g++ 4.3.4
t.cpp:6: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'A::x_'
t.cpp:8: error: from this location

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you're getting an error from your compiler (when it works under 4.6.1) suggests a potential compiler bug that's fixed in later versions. That said, it's unusual to use `BOOST_TYPEOF` on your own data members - after all, you should know what type they are, right? If you're looking to consolidate some complex logic to determine the right type, just use a `typedef`:

```
private:
  typedef int data_type;
  data_type x_;
public:
  data_type x() { return x_; }
```